# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch - Google Spreadsheet API - Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I have difficulties with OAuth to connect to Google Spreadsheet. I spent few days searching and trying to fix it on my own. Now I can not find anything that I do wrong.

I tried to play with URI adrresses, I tried to change OAuth json. I searched stack-overflow and it seems obvious but till now any fix did not work for me.

Here is what I did in python as it was described in https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample

```
creds = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'C:\\Users\\pavel\\Disk Google\\finance\\nemovitosti\\nemovitostiSecretOauth.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8000)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
spreadsheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  

# Values will be appended after the last row of the table.
range_ = 'A2:BL2'

# How the input data should be interpreted.
value_input_option = 'RAW'

# How the input data should be inserted.
insert_data_option = 'INSERT_ROWS'

value_range_body = {"values": [["a", "b"]], "range": "A1:B1"}

request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

**Google console:**

[image]

**json file**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At your script, the redirect URI is created like `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/`. In this case, the registered "Authorized redirect URIs" is different from it. By this, such error occurs. So in this case, please modify `http://localhost:8000` to `http://localhost:8000/` at "Authorized redirect URIs" as follows and test it again.

[image]

#### Note:

- And, in this case, it seems that even when `http://localhost:8000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000` of "Authorized JavaScript origins" are removed, the authorization works.

Comment: Thanks! Works!. Added slash and removed URI "Authorized JavaScript origins".